More space on disk taken than actual files Win 11
Windows says that 207 GB of space is used, but when I sum it up, it amounts to 153 GB. This is an SSD disk, and Windows says it is optimised.
Update: I deleted the recycle bin, and it freed 9 GB, but still, what takes the 40 GB / Windowsindows recovery or temporary?f, but how do I fix it, or what takes this space?


How exactly are you estimate your disk usage? Are you using an effective method to do that calculation? Just clicking properties on the entire disk is NOT effective.

@Ramhound thank you! do you know is it better to copy my system disk on another free ssd disk I have 465 GB or just reinstall the apps taking most space on it?

I would just use a third-party application to clone the drive.
